# How to put image link in img tag using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do is show the image to img tag using ajax and php.

My problem is after receiving the link of the image from the emailName.php the image wont show up.

I check the emailName.php it sends this array to the ajax:

```
{"user_lname":"Oppa","user_code":"1","user_image":"myDocuments\/images\/default.jpg"}
```

The user_lname and user_code are showing up but the image is not.

I want to show the image on this tag.

```
<img id="profileImage" name="profileImage" />
<label id="emailNameResult"></label>
<label id="emailCodeResult"></label>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



var countTimerEmailName = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
        emailName();        
        }, 500);


var  $emailNameResult = $('#emailNameResult');

function emailName(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"emailName.php",
        type:"GET",
        data: { term : $('#email').val() },
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function(result) {

        $("#emailNameResult").html(result.user_lname);
        $("#emailCodeResult").html(result.user_code);
        $("#profileImage").html(result.user_image);

        }

    });

};

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `attr()` to change the `src`

```
$("#profileImage").attr('src', result.user_image);
```

**[attr() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

This assumes that the `<img>` tag shown already exists